# How do i run "npm run watch" on server for a laravel project?

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm

I have a problem, i can't seem to find the answer if you would be kind to help me.

I am trying to update changes made on the code instantly with "np m run watch", the problem is that i don't know how to do that on server. All the files are on server not on my computer( i'm using ssh connection on visual studio)  to run the commands "cd c:// ..." and run in there. How do i do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Using another ssh connection you can just run `npm run watch` on the server

Comment: Does your server have node and npm installed on it?

Comment: Yes, it does,  i just don't know how to create the command on the server, if i open the terminal in visual studio, nothing happens.

Comment: @Allcro Is there a `package.json` file? That is where the the npm commands are declared. You should be running the commands from the directory that the `package.json` file exists in. This should be in the root of your project.

Comment: @JamesTotty  ""scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    etc ," this is the code in package.json, if i write the one about run watch on the console  it tells me it couldn't find the file. I am sure that i don't know how to open the terminal on the server there..

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, i had to go into the server " ssh user@host"  and then go to the files "cd.... etc"  Thank you for the help!